# gruntjs grunt-init grunfile throws error Fatal error: Arguments to path.join must be strings

Tags: gruntjs

I am trying to set up a new project with gruntjs 0.4. I've uninstalled 0.3 and installed the grunt-cli and imported grunt-init gruntfile. when I run "grunt-init gruntfile" it runs the same as it did in 0.3 asking the normal questions

> Please answer the following: [?] Is the DOM involved in ANY way? (Y/n)
>   y [?] Will files be concatenated or minified? (Y/n) y [?] Will you
>   have a package.json file? (Y/n) y [?] Do you need to make any changes
>   to the above before continuing? (y/N) n

however after answering all the questions I get the error

> Fatal error: Arguments to path.join must be strings

Has anyone else dealt with something similar or can you point me in the right direction to debug?

Answer (score 5):

It was a bug caused by a change in Node 0.10.0, and was [fixed](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/commit/c6f83ca060e46a0e94160cd64e57cc80aa23917d) earlier today. Will be released soon.

Comment: hi Sindre, do you know if it has been released? I still get this issue.

Comment: grunt 0.4.1 which includes the fix was released on the 13th. Though this is a widespread breakage, so you might experience it with other modules too. I would always recommend waiting a while before upgrading Node.js or any platform you depend on. From experience, something will always break.

Answer (score 3):

I just updated both grunt and grunt-cli

```
npm install grunt-cli
.
.
.
npm install grunt
```

and that fixed it for me

Answer (score 2):

if you're using 'bower'(A package manager for the web), I had the same issue, It turned that its a bower library error when try to install angular. I run the bower build separately like below

```
bower install angular
```

Then I selected the correct version, and it works for me.