# "Arguments to path.join must be strings" in grunt using expand option

Tags: coffeescript, gruntjs

It's not duplicate to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15382662/grunt-fail-build-arguments-to-path-join-must-be-strings-error) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15365996/gruntjs-grunt-init-grunfile-throws-error-fatal-error-arguments-to-path-join-mus) question. Very similar though.

My goal is simple - compile coffeescript files, so I have this Gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt){
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        coffee:{
            compile: {
                expand: true,
                flatten: true,
                cwd: 'js/',
                src: ['*.coffee'],
                dest: ['js/prod/'],
                ext: '.js'
            }           
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-coffee');
};
```

After running `grunt coffee' I had **Warning: Arguments to path.join must be strings Use --force to continue.** and nothing was compiled. Why?

I don't think that I need to reinstall something, because I've installed grunt two days ago, not before any bugfixes was done related to this issue. And I know I can use another syntax, but I need this **expand** option turning on.

Comment: @user1737909 No, it's Debian Squeeze

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `dest` should be a `String` instead of an `Array`:

```
module.exports = function(grunt){
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        coffee:{
            compile: {
                expand: true,
                flatten: true,
                cwd: 'js/',
                src: ['*.coffee'],
                dest: 'js/prod/',
                ext: '.js'
            }           
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-coffee');
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Though the previous answer should have resolved your issue if not then try to run the below command.

```
npm cache clean && rm -rf node_modules/grunt && npm install grunt
```